# How to have maximum characters in a text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I do not understand how to have a maximum of 4 charachters allowed in the text widget. At the moment, when the buttons are pressed an infinite amount of numbers are shown in the text widget. Example: 123456 but i only want 1234 for this case to be shown.

Also if possible how do you change the size of the window that contains all the widgets as at the moment, the window is much larger than the widgets whereas i just want it to be the same length. Images to the sizing are shown below:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsBrz.png)

[What i want the window size to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2mg8.png)

Comment: Put event on related object and replace text to text[:4].

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by put event on related object? Can you show me?. Sorry new to python and tkinter

Comment: Did my answer not solve your problem?

Comment: i dont really understand how to put that in my code, the theory of it i can understand but actually doing it not really

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on "how to have a maximum of 4 charachters allowed": you need to have a validation in your program:
Assuming that you only want integer numbers in the range of [1-4] (1, 2, 3, 4):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def valFunc(txt):
    if len(txt) <= 4:
        try:
            txt = int(txt)
            return True
        except:
            return False
    else:
        return False

vcmd = root.register(valFunc)

e = Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, "%P"))
e.pack()
```

And for the window size you need to use a `geometry` method for your window.